# How to do integration test in spring data neo4j (SDN4)

Tags: neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I want to write integration tests in a project which uses spring data neo4j version 4 (SDN4) in context of a spring boot application.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 4):

The Cineasts example application for SDN4 has tests here: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-cineasts/tree/master/src/test/java/org/neo4j/cineasts

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I tried to rewrite my tests according the sdn-cineasts way. But it worked only for simple cases. e.g. I have init (spring) beans which check the db for "prepopulation" (e.g. is an admin user available when not than create one etc.) and this func does not work with the approach to extend the test class from WrappingServerIntegrationTest because of I have no "connection" to the database when this func. is running.

Comment: I'm not clear about what you're asking- do you mean you want a handle to the GraphDatabaseService? If so, theres a getDatabase() you can use

Comment: I have trouble to initialize data. For this reason I have a spring bean which implements CommandLineRunner and populate the database (e.g. with an default admin user when not existing but with spring data repositories). But this func. makes huge troubles. E.g. when I run the app as "normal" web app the neo4j session is defined with "@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)". So the session is not available. I get an error on "Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread". In integration tests I worked around by execute func. in @Before methods...

Answer (score 2):

Your integration tests can use a mocking framework such as Spring's MockMvc to avoid the need to start up a web container. If you don't want them to run in a web context at all you can use a different configuration file for testing that doesn't specify a session-scoped bean.

The integration tests in the SDN 4 codebase take both of these approaches.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/tree/4.0/spring-data-neo4j/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/integration

Comment: The problem is not not the integration test rather to use the neo4j session in context of a "web" session (in "normal" webserver mode). In this case the session is not available for batch tasks or startup tasks (right?). It is ok to define the neo4j session without spring scope "session"????

Comment: I haven't tried this, but you should be able to create more than one instance of the Neo4jSession bean if you need this feature. Keep the usual session-scoped bean for the web app, and create an additional application-scoped Neo4jSession bean for your startup tasks. Obviously the bean names will have to be different, but you can then inject the application-scoped instance in your CommandLineRunner. (I am assuming you're relying on the behaviour of Spring Boot to invoke the CommandLineRunner beans for you). Bear in mind that the two Neo4jSession beans will not be able to share mapping contexts.

Comment: Another approach would be to ditch the idea of CommandLineRunner, and instead create a bean implementing BeanPostProcessor. In the `postProcessAfterInitialization` method, wait for Spring to instantiate the Neo4jSession bean, and then call your startup code passing in the bean directly.

Comment: I tried also BeanPostProcessor. But this approach has the same problems like CommandLineRunner. And using another session bean it also not a good idea because you are not able to use the spring data repository stuff.... (I can not imagine how to explain the spring data repository stuff which session to use)